# Excluding records in select when rank functions is not enough

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, rank, knapsack-problem

I'm stuck in select query to get best match from table like this:

| Name | A | B | TotalA | TotalB |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Name1 | 10 | 1 | 10 | 1 |
| Name2 | 15 | 2 | 25 | 3 |
| Name3 | 20 | 3 | 45 | 6 |
| Name4 | 25 | 4 | 70 | 10 |
| Name5 | 30 | 5 | 100 | 15 |
| Name6 | 35 | 6 | 135 | 21 |
| Name7 | 51 | 7 | 175 | 28 |
| ..... | .... | ...... | ...... | ...... |
| ..... | .... | ...... | ...... | ...... |

I'm trying to find best 6 records with the lowest sum of B, but there's additional condition that sum of A need to be higher than 150.

This table is sorted by B, and the best results is on the top. So sum of B from 6 top results is 21, but in this case sum of A is 135 which is lower than 150. So record nb 6 should be excluded and the next nb 7 should be included. So the best result is sum of B = 22 from records 1-5 and 7, while sum of A is 151, which is enough.

I used rank function with partition and order but every time query returned 0 records. Is there any possibility to exclude this 6th record and take 7 to the result, so sum of A will be > 150?

Comment: And please show sample data and desired results as 2 separate tables of data. Ideally provide sample data as DDL+DML as that makes it much easier to assist.

Comment: This is very close to being a "travelling salesman" problem. There isn't a SQL friendly way to approach it, other than brute force; check ***all*** combinations of rows and see which combination(s) are the best match. Which is going to be brutal. Perhaps describing the context would help? If you explain more about why you want this, and what behaviors exist in your data, we might be able to suggest less brutal options?

Comment: @MatBailie I'd say more like the knapsack problem, except in reverse: total A higher than x and total B as low as possible, with a fixed number of items. Either way it's NP-complete

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be a variation on the [*knapsack problem*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem), which is NP-Complete, and the easiest (to code) solution is just brute-forcing every permutation.

Given that you have a fixed number of items, you can do this by self-joining

```sql
SELECT TOP (1)
  *
FROM Items i1
JOIN Items i2 ON i2.Name > i1.Name
JOIN Items i3 ON i3.Name > i2.Name
JOIN Items i4 ON i4.Name > i3.Name
JOIN Items i5 ON i5.Name > i4.Name
JOIN Items i6 ON i6.Name > i5.Name
CROSS APPLY (VALUES (
    i1.A + i2.A + i3.A + i4.A + i5.A + i6.A,
    i1.B + i2.B + i3.B + i4.B + i5.B + i6.B
)) v(TotalA, TotalB)
WHERE TotalA > 150
ORDER BY
  TotalB;
```

> `Name` in this case is just a proxy for some unique column

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=1001b4ac200450ed036b03c2b6c6ace4)

There may be more efficient solutions, depending on your exact problem.

Comment: I hadn't noticed that it's always exactly 6 items, which does limit the combinations somewhat. It's still worth noting just how quickly this grows. At 10 names, this generates just 210 combinations (some not having 6 items, so excluded by the inner joins). At 20 names, that reaches 43,796 combinations. I certainly wouldn't want this to run for hundreds of names. Making `depending on your exact problem` exceedingly important.  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=438e088b70c3a5e6af9159a0817d9051

Comment: Hey guys, thank you very much for your tips! I tried your proposal with joining 6 tables and check all combination and it really works. The query returns correct values. The thing is that it takes a while on the database engine. So now I will make some efficiency tests. The main conclusion is - SQL is not the best way for calculations like knapsack problem, as Charlieface wisely mention. Maybe better code it on application side, or make the calculations with some period and save results in some table. Once again many thanks, I apprecciate your help.

Comment: Your best bet is to look for efficiencies, for example memoization will substantially reduce the number of possible options. This is indeed much easier in procedural code